# Android UI Hangs on JDBC Connection - Even though Connection is on another Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jdbc, android-handler

So, I have a login screen. Upon pressing the 'Login' `Button` a JDBC `Connection` is made to check the username and password and then move onto the next `Activity` if the details are correct. As a result of this, the UI hangs for approximately 5 second. I assumed that this was because the connection was created in the same `Thread`, so I created a new one. I then created a `Handler` to interact with the UI depending on what happened with this connection.

The trouble is, the UI still hangs. Below is where the new Runnable is declared in the Activity (`h` is the custom `Handler` reference belonging to this `Activity`);

```
    logInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                new LoginProcessor(h).run(); // HERE!
                }});
```

Below is the run() method from the `LoginProcessor` `Runnable` which includes the code that is causing the hang. The `MicroManager` class contains simple JDBC database interactions and makes the connection (nothing exciting in there really and I am trying to keep this as short as possible);

```
public void run() {
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    try{                   
        MicroManager manager = new MicroManager(); // THIS LINE, AND THE LINE BELOW, ARE CAUSING THE HANG!!!!
        if(manager.getEmployeeId(h.getLoginName(), h.getPassword())!= 0){
            h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        h.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }        
}
```

In the above, there is no direct interaction with the UI. Information is simply sent to the `Handler` so that it can do it on the UI thread. Lastly, here are the methods of my custom `Handler` called `LogInHandler`;

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
    if(msg.what == 0){
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, AdvisorsPanelActivity.class));
        activity.finish();
    }else{
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();               
        alertDialog.setTitle("Not Working");
        alertDialog.show();
        activity.setProgressVisible(ProgressBar.GONE);
    }
}

public String getLoginName(){
    return activity.getLoginName();
}

public String getPassword(){
    return activity.getPassword();
}
```

Sorry to dump so much code on your guys, but I didn't think a complete picture was possible without all the above. I've trimmed it down as much as I can. I've only recently started working with Threading AND Android, so please be gentle with me.

Comment: Also, only use JDBC if you really have to. A WebService is a much better approach regarding reliability, safety and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience: Use **AsyncTask** for JDBC and you shall torture no more.

**EDIT :**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) is a neat example of implementing AsyncTask:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.System;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // because we implement OnClickListener we only have to pass "this"
        // (much easier)
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // detect the view that was "clicked"
        switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        break;
    }
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

You may want to create and handle your JDBC connection in
 doInBackground(String... params) part of your code.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some reading to do. Would you be able to add some basic code demonstrating how an `AsyncTask` could be used? Apologies if I am asking for a bit much.